# Cannot add Custom Action in Visual Studio 2010 installer project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, installation

I converted a working project from Visual Studio 2008 to VS2010. The C++ solution builds a single executable and 3 DLLs, and a windows installer project.

After converting to VS2010, I received a build error:

> Unable to build custom action named 'Primary Output from xxxx (Active)' from project output group 'Primary Output' because the project output group does not have a key file.

I removed and re-added the output groups, then attempted to add a custom action. The executable output was not listed as a candidate for a custom action. I then noticed when I selected the executable **"Primary Output"** properties, that the `KeyOutput` property was set to (None) and was grayed out.

When revisiting the VS2008 version, the `KeyOutput` property was not grayed out. I found the error message on MSDN, with a useless fix:

> Remove the custom action and replace it with a custom action pointing to a project output group that has a key file.

Obviously, the tech writer didn't know how to fix it either. Keep in mind the original build worked and installed correctly. I believe the root issue is why the `KeyOutput` property is disabled - but why? (When viewing **"Outputs"** it correctly shows the EXE or DLL in each project).

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and I figured out why the setup project could not find the key output files.

My project Output Directory was defined as $(SolutionDir)\bin\$(Platform).  SolutionDir already has a trailing backslash so the \bin was placing a double backslash in the path.  The project would build fine but the setup project couldn't resolve the key outputs.  Setting the output to $(SolutionDir)bin\$(Platform)\ resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

After further investigation, I found this is a bug in Visual Studio 2010.

If you specify an output name for a project that differs from the name of the project itself, it fails to do the right thing.

To reproduce this, change

<kbd>Project properties</kbd>-><kbd>Linker</kbd>-><kbd>General</kbd>-><kbd>OutputFile</kbd> from `$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)` to be something like `$(OutDir)foobar.exe`.

The project then changes the `KeyOutput` value to empty, and is not available for custom actions in installations. No workaround other than living with the default project naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

Very late answer but hopefully it will save someone the 2 hours I spent banging my head on the wall with VS 2010 ( what an awful piece of software it is - slow to load and takes up 300 megs of working memory per devenv , and now this bug!!!!!????) here goes -
Roger Dunn was correct is saying that it is the Project properties->Linker->General->OutputFile that causes the problem - if you have something like $(OutDir)foobar.exe the custom action barfs , if you change it back to $(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt) it works again!

The work around is to change the macro $(TargetName) to foobar and then user $(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt) if you want custom name for your exe.

$(TargetName) can be changed at - Project properties->Configuration Properties->general->TargetName.

But what a waste of time this VS 2010.